# How to print parameters of an output from a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, lapply

Using the dataset df, I sample from various values of v coupled with x to generate a randomized J (as shown in the function). The output of that randomization is stored is results. Along with rand.cor = f(x,v), I also want the table to generate the associated x, v that it picked for the run and and the y.sample generated. I tried adding ax,v but I noticed that it was simply repeating the vector in original x and v, not the randomized ones.

```
set.seed(333)
J <- rnorm(40, 5, 1)
x <- rnorm(40, 2, 1)
v <- rnorm(40, 10, 1)
sp <- rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each=10)

df <- data.frame(J, x, v, sp)


library(data.table)
setDT(df)
#function to estimate model coefficients
f <- function(x, v) {
  v.sample <- sample(v, length(v), replace=TRUE)
  y.sample <- (v.sample/x^2) - (1/x)
  per <- cor(y.sample, x, use="complete.obs")
}
    

# 999 models for each species
result <- rbindlist(
  lapply(1:999, \(i) df[, .(rand.cor = f(x, v), x, v), sp][, i:=i])
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the current function `f` returns `rand.corr` vector only. So if we would like to get other vectors defined in `f` (i.e, v.sample, y.sample) then we need to add one more line returning all vectors into a dataframe and then joining it with `x`, `v`, `sp`, and `i` in the `result`because in the current result, only `rand.corr` would be stored, so we need to remove the `rand.corr=` from the `lapply()` function to get all vectors returned from `f`:

```
set.seed(333)
J <- rnorm(40, 5, 1)
x <- rnorm(40, 2, 1)
v <- rnorm(40, 10, 1)
sp <- rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each=10)

df <- data.frame(J, x, v, sp)

library(data.table)
setDT(df)

f <- function(x, v) {
  v.sample <- sample(v, length(v), replace=TRUE)
  y.sample <- (v.sample/x^2) - (1/x)
  per <- cor(y.sample, x, use="complete.obs")
# storing all vectors in a dataframe
  data.frame( v.sample = v.sample, y.sample = y.sample, rand.cor = per)
}

result <- rbindlist(
  lapply(1:999, \(i)  df[, .(f(x, v),x,v, sp)][, i:=i])
)

head(result) # a dataframe with 39960 rows

   v.sample   y.sample   rand.cor         x         v sp i
1: 10.515567  1.9575322 -0.3232905 2.0763333 10.419046  A 1
2: 10.159445  2.6790438 -0.3232905 1.7696440 10.920101  A 1
3:  9.581106  1.3524713 -0.3232905 2.3174648  8.802001  A 1
4: 10.164441 58.8111686 -0.3232905 0.4073156  8.568937  A 1
5: 10.948986  2.7624775 -0.3232905 1.8180594  9.581106  A 1
6: 10.164441  0.4542123 -0.3232905 3.7561417 10.233590  A 1
```

Hope thats what you are looking for.